# Copy Wordpress site to another domain

Tags: wordpress, administration

I have two domains (mysite.com and mysite.net) which share the same IP address. I can see that in my host control panel. I've created a Wordpress site on mysite.com, beforehand installing Wordpress using FTP. Now I want to have the same wordpress site on mysite.net, which will have the same content in different language. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the files to the other site. Then export the database, find/replace 'mysite.com' with 'mysite.net' and import it into the database for mysite.net. Modify your wp-config.php file to refer to the new database.

Then, on mysite.net/wp-admin, go to Settings->Permalinks and save it. This will reset the rewrite rules and create a new .htaccess file (when writable).

Comment: Thank you. But where should I export the database ?

Comment: Does your hosting provider offer PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: Then you can navigate to the database from 'mysite.com', click 'Export' and hit Go! After editing the file that's being generated, you can navigate to the database from 'mysite.net' and import that file.

Comment: Thank man. Unfortunately I am getting "#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server" error when i try to log in. Do you know why it can happen?

Comment: Wrong login data? Ask your hosting provider for that ;)

Comment: Thank you, it somewhat worked. Some custom design are not displaying properly for some reason, which is kinda strange, because I imported from the same DB.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any 'hard-coded' urls in your theme?

Comment: I only need to change the DB file right? No need to change WP files or is there?

Comment: Well, if there are hardcoded urls in your wp-files, like your theme, then you need to change them too